# how to monitor "create user" action on linux platform?

Tags: linux, monitor

currently on linux platform,

if someone or some app create a user.

Does other apps be able to get this message immediately?

if yes, app can use which way to know a user is created ?

thanks in advance

Comment: is polling on /etc/passwd file every x seconds enough for you?

Comment: thanks. but this is not what I want. I just wonder if there is some scheme to notify other user a new user is created.

Answer (score 0):

You may use similar script like below to examine the /etc/passwd file continuously. You may vary "sleep" command to determine the delay. If you run this script in background, it will send mail when new users are added or removed. You can feed these results to desired application by altering the code.

```
#!/bin/bash

unalias cp &>/dev/null

OLD=`wc -l "/etc/passwd" | awk '{print $1}'` && /bin/cp -f /etc/passwd /etc/passwd.old


while true ; do

sleep 1

NEW=`wc -l "/etc/passwd" | awk '{print $1}'` && MID=${NEW} && /bin/cp -f /etc/passwd /etc/passwd.copy

 if [[ ${NEW} -gt ${OLD} ]]

   then

   DIFF=`expr ${NEW} - ${OLD}`

   USERS=`tail -n ${DIFF} "/etc/passwd.copy" | awk -F: '{ print $1 }'`

   echo -e "New user(s):\n ${USERS} " | mail -s "New Users Created! at `date +%c`" admin@mail.com

 elif [[ ${NEW} -lt ${OLD} ]]

   then

   USERS=`diff -y /etc/passwd /etc/passwd.old | awk -F">" '{print $2}'| awk -F: '{print $1}' | grep -E -v "^$"`

   echo -e "User(s)removed:\n ${USERS[@]}" | mail -s "Users removed at `date +%c`" admin@mail.com

 fi

sleep 1

OLD=${MID} && /bin/cp -f /etc/passwd.copy /etc/passwd.old

done
```